# Graph rendering not working as expected

Tags: graphs-and-networks, version-6

I'm running the older Mathematica v6 which seems to go through
the edges of graphs twice.  Is this a bug?  Is it fixed on the
latest version?  Please just try this command:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1},
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[True, Print["e ", ##]; Black] &),
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (If[True, Print["v ", ##]; Black] &)]
```

```
v {0.496926,0.867793}11
e {{0.496926,0.867793},{0.999994,0.00354563}}{1,2}None{1,2}
e {{0.999994,0.00354563},{0.,0.}}{2,3}None{2,3}
e {{0.,0.},{0.496926,0.867793}}{3,1}None{3,1}
e {{0.496926,0.867793},{0.999994,0.00354563}}{1,2}None{1,2}
e {{0.999994,0.00354563},{0.,0.}}{2,3}None{2,3}
e {{0.,0.},{0.496926,0.867793}}{3,1}None{3,1}
v {0.496926,0.867793}11
v {0.999994,0.00354563}22
v {0.,0.}33
```

Comment: Please do not use [bug] as tag unless the problem has been confirmed as bug by WRI.

Comment: Same result in version 9.0.1. I don't understand why this occurs. Good question.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug.  Edges are only rendered once, and it shouldn't be of concern how many times the edge rendering function is evaluated.  You should construct the edge rendering function so it has no side effects, and the number of times it's evaluated has no effect on the result.

Comment: @m_goldberg ... or [a number of SE users agrees it's a bug](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/355/57).

Comment: If it's a problem you can wrap the function in `Hold` and release it after the graphics expression is created: `GraphPlot[{1->2,2->3,3->1},EdgeRenderingFunction->Hold[(Print["e ",##];Arrow[#1,0.1])&]]//ReleaseHold`

Comment: Evaluating the expression in the MathKernel yields the same printed messages, which is not obvious, as that is not the case in the related questions [Caching of Graph Graphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23851/4330) and [Graph does not evaluate some options when not displayed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23190/4330).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your code gives the same result on Mathematica 9.0.1, a similar expression using `Graph` (versions 8 and above only):

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1},
 EdgeShapeFunction   -> ((Print["e ", ##]; {Red, Arrow[#]}) &), 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ((Print["v ", ##]; {Green, Disk[#1, .025]}) &)]
```

gives these results:

```
e {{-0.866025,-0.5},{0.866025,-0.5}} 1 -> 2
e {{0.866025,-0.5},{1.83697*10^-16,1.}} 2 ->3
e {{1.83697*10^-16,1.},{-0.866025,-0.5}} 3 ->1
v {-0.866025,-0.5} 1 {0.0203996,0.0203996}
v {0.866025,-0.5} 2 {0.0203996,0.0203996}
v {1.83697*10^-16,1.} 3 {0.0203996,0.0203996}
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks for the v9 check and workaround.  I can't agree with those who don't want to call this a bug.  Maybe GraphPlot is just slower than necessary (but I suspect that edge graphics also get rendered twice which could effect non-opaque alpha-level objects), so maybe it's minor, but I'm sure the original Mathematica designer did not intend for this.  By the way, I don't have access to v9, so am working around the bug in other ways.

Comment: @bobuhito given the shift to new graphing functions in 8 and 9, perhaps this 'bug' isn't so likely to be fixed. (and thanks for accept:)